# How to handle inpage confirm/delete in jquery

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, confirmation

I have a requirement to create an in page confirm before a deletion of a tag occurs. I basically want to use a div that shows when a tag is clicked and if someone clicks outside the div or clicks "no" everything resets and if they click "yes" the item deletes and the dialog hides.

Here's the code that gets called on click of a tag

```
removeGroup: function( evt ) {

  var groupList = this.$el.find('.js-group-list');
  var groupTags = groupList.find('.tag');
  var clickedTag = $(evt.currentTarget).closest('.tag');
  var index = groupTags.index(clickedTag);
  var groupSections = $('.js-favorite-group');
  // add one to account for "All" section
  var groupToRemove = groupSections.eq(index + 1);
  var removedGroupName = this.getGroupNameForSection(groupToRemove);
  var all = groupSections.eq(0);
  var allContainer = allDoctors.find('.js-favorite-row-container');
  clickedTag.addClass('is-active');
  $('.delete-acct-message').show().focus();

  var confirmed = this.removeGroupConfirm( evt );
  if ( confirmed ){
    groupToRemove.find('.js-favorite-row').appendTo(allDoctorsContainer);
    clickedTag.remove();
    groupToRemove.remove();
    this.updateSectionDropdowns();
    this.ariaAlert('Group ' + removedGroupName + ' removed');
    this.hideConfirm(evt);
  }
}
```

And here's the function for the confirmation box

```
removeGroupConfirm: function(evt){ 
  $('.js-remove-yes').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    return true;  
  });
  $('.js-remove-no').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.hideConfirm(evt);
    return false;  
  });
  var container = $('.delete-acct-message');

  if ( container.is( ':visible' ) ) {
    if (!container.is(evt.target) && container.has(evt.target).length === 0) {
      //this.hideConfirm(evt);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

What's the best way to structure this in order to interrupt the deletion process and wait for and return a true or false? Help set me straight on where I'm going wrong. I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around it looked like what I needed to implement was a callback to use a div as a confirm dialog.

```
removeGroup: function( evt ) {
  var callback = function () {
    groupToRemove.find('.js-favorite-doctor-row').appendTo(allContainer);
    clickedTag.remove();
    groupToRemove.remove();
    that.updateSectionDropdowns();
    that.ariaAlert('Group ' + removedGroupName + ' removed');
    that.hideConfirm(evt);
  }
  this.showAlert(evt, callback);
  var groupList = this.$el.find('.js-group-list');
  var groupTags = groupList.find('.tag');
  var clickedTag = $(evt.currentTarget).closest('.tag');
  var index = groupTags.index(clickedTag);
  var groupSections = $('.js-favorite-group');
  // add one to account for "All Doctors" section
  var groupToRemove = groupSections.eq(index + 1);
  var removedGroupName = this.getGroupNameForSection(groupToRemove);
  var all = groupSections.eq(0);
  var allContainer = all.find('.js-favorite-row-container');
  clickedTag.addClass('is-active');



},

showAlert: function (evt, callback) {
  that = this;
  $('.delete-acct-message').show().focus();
  $('.js-remove-yes').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    callback(); 
  });
  $('.js-remove-no').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.hideConfirm(evt);
  });
},


removeGroupConfirm: function(evt){ 
  that = this;
  that.showAlert(evt, that, callback);
},
```